# How to create a function to visualize employee salary distribution?

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

I would like to see the salary distribution by employees' job categories so that I could see if someone is overpaid or underpaid.

Here is a part of my dataset:

```
Category        Salary      Status
Analyst          35           1
Analyst          42           0
Manager          55           0
Administrator    25           1
..................................
```

Status means whether an employee has terminated or not. 1 means no, 0 means yes.

So, first I selected the still active employees as
    active = data[data['Status']==1]

But I have no idea how to select the job category in order to create a corresponding distribution plot for the salary distribution.

```
sns.distplot(active.Category =='Analyst',kde=False, bins=30)
```

How to add the Salary column in the code?

Is there a way to def a function that each time I input the Category then it would give me the plot for the salary distribution??

I am new to the algorithms and would like to know if anyone can help.

Comment: `active[active.Category =='Analyst']['Salary']` try this for selecting salary column

Comment: Do you know how to define a function that each time I only need to input the category data and get the desired visualized graph?

Comment: already did that in answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define function as follows

```
def plotSalary(category):
    sns.distplot(active[active.Category ==category]['Salary'],kde=False, bins=30)

plotSalary('Analyst')
```